# Outlook 2010 disabled customize preview

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I wrote a custom form in outlook 2010 that for reprocessing message.  When I focused on an email the preview panel showed "this item contains active content that cannot be displayed". But When I double click email and open a new message form everything is ok.

I supposed does any group policy or outlook settings disabled this action?

help me!

Best Regards,
Sue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means your custom one-off form contains a script, or at least Outlook thinks that it does.

Comment: No, I tested in my lab and another colleagues labs, all works. it just can be reproduced on another machine. 
my custom activity invoked on outlook item_read action. when I open the email the action works fine,  just preview activity not works.
Is it possible some dll was be disabled that affect this problem? I saw mssphtb.dll be disabled in outlook add-in settings.

Best Regards,
Sue.

Comment: Again, Outlook *thinks* your one-off form has a script - take a look at the message with OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) - click IMessage button, look at the SideEffects named property.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I will take a look at customer's lab.

Comment: I have a question, if this property is 1, I change it to 0 then save message. It will be change back to 1 again, if I re-click the message.

Comment: 1 is fine (it is seOpenToDelete bit). You want to make sure there is no seHasScript (0x2000).

Comment: Another question, how did you find this property, cause I googled it, I couldn't found any website described this property.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/partnercenter/cc842271.aspx

Comment: Thanks again. By the way Outlook Spy is very powerful, it is a good plug-in for our devs.